# ios: delegate doesn't respond

Tags: ios, delegates

i'm trying to create my first delegate here's what i'm trying to do

at class called PAStepper.h i did this

```
@class PAStepper;
@protocol StepperDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)didIncrement;
-(void)didDecrement;


@end

@interface PAStepper : UIControl
{
    __weak id <StepperDelegate> stepperDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <StepperDelegate> stepperDelegate;
@end
```

and synthized the property of course in the .m file

and then putten in the PAStepper.m  the following in a method

```
[self.stepperDelegate didDecrement];
```

in the controller i want to take the delegate i did this

.h

```
@interface OCSideCartViewController : UIViewController<StepperDelegate>
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PAStepper *stepper = [[PAStepper alloc]init];
    stepper.stepperDelegate = self;
}



-(void)didIncrement{
    NSLog(@"inc");
}
-(void)didDecrement{
    NSLog(@"dec");

}
```

knowing that this class is viewController that contain a table that every cell have PAStepper .. all i wanted that the delegate call didIncrement and didDecrement whenever i press the buttons

Comment: Check whenever you are calling delegate methods using `[self.stepperDelegate didDecrement];`, does your `stepperDelegate` has any reference or nill?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong! When do you call [self.stepperDelegate didDecrement]; Show more code

Comment: What's holding on to `stepper`? It's a local variable, and (if you are using ARC) it will be released at the end of the method's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this method

```
[self.stepperDelegate didDecrement];
```

NSLog you stepperDelegate and ensure it is not null. Can you confirm the method which calls your delegate is being called?

Comment: self.stepperDelegate is really null!! what should i do!

Comment: Cool I think what is happening is PAStepper *stepper = [[PAStepper alloc]init]; is being deallocated. Maybe make that an instance variable. So it would be self.stepper = [[PAStepper alloc] init];

Comment: Have you set it to **id <StepperDelegate> stepperDelegate** and **@property (nonatomic, strong) id <StepperDelegate> stepperDelegate;** ?

Comment: @sbarow delegate instance shouldn't be strong (in ARC) or retain (in non ARC) it should be weak or assign respectively. Do you read Apple docs?

Comment: @sbarow whenever you are retaining or making strong a delegate then it creates a dependency between those two classes, so both of them won't get released because of this cyclic dependency. So delegate must be weak or assign.

Comment: ok till now i did this 
    self.stepper = [[PAStepper alloc]init];
    self.stepper.stepperDelegate = self;

self.stepper.stepperDelegate is not null here cause it's with self

it's null in [self.stepperDelegate didDecrement]; in the PAStepper class itself!!

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab I think you are calling the delegate method before setting the delegate. So you are getting it as nil.

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Can you paste the code? @Searching thanks for the info by the way.

Comment: i'm calling [self.stepperDelegate didDecrement]; in a method inside PAStepper  my whole problem was that PAStepper 
https://github.com/mperovic/PAStepper
have no delegates at all

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab So you have uploaded the project in github?

Comment: no it's the controller i'm using :) i can't upload it to github it's for a company

Comment: Are you subclassing PAStepper (it indicates UIControl) ? The link you posted are you using that project? If so you should be subclassing it and then implementing your own delegate.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/zip/b68YQ12H/testDelegate.html
 you can  check what i do here..

Comment: i've put the a whole project not just snippt

Comment: thanks i got it.. it was all about init .. i should get already initialized steeper

Answer (score 0):

you can call this in your pastapper.h file

```
if ([stepperDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didIncrement)])
{
    [stepperDelegate performSelector:@selector(didIncrement)];
}
```

Comment: if the protocol declares that the method is required, you should not need to check if it responds to a specific method, because it has to, or the compiler will flag it.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t download the project, so i am guessing..

Is the Stepper in the Interface Builder?
If yes you don´t have to allocate it.

1. Make an Outlet Connection of the Stepper in the OCSideCartViewController.
2. Post this in OCSideCartViewController:

---

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{     
     self.stepper.stepperDelegate = self;
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

If the Stepper is not an Outlet, you have to add it to your ViewControllers view after setting it´s bounds..